# Aerospike Nodejs register UDF with .lua file

Tags: node.js, lua, aerospike

here is my problem.

I have registered module like this

```
asclient.client.udfRegister('./lua/lm.lua', function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error: %s [%d]', error.message, error.code)
  }
});
```

After this peace of code i check if my module is registered correctly

```
aql> show modules
```

and the output is

```
| "lm.lua" | "824bf77bff0f8b35c4eacc5ddcee82b1802a0c63" | "LUA" |
```

so i am pretty sure that module is loaded

Then i try to apply some functions in that lm.lua file

```
var ctoken = '0878d655bd4c438236b060b9b1c1d2af';
var key = new Key('namespace', 'set', 12345)
var udf = { module: 'lm', funcname: 'getlm', args: [ctoken]}
asquery.client.apply(key, udf, function (error, result) {
  if (error) throw error
    console.log(result);
});
```

The content of lua file is

```
   function getlm(stream, conv)

    local function transformer(rec)
        local touple = map()
        touple["1"] = rec["1"]
        touple["2"] = rec["2"]
        touple["3"] = rec["3"]
        return touple
    end

    return stream:map(transformer)
end
```

Basically i map all the fields in AS and just want to return some result to be sure its work properly, but for some reason always return

```
AerospikeError: /opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/lm.lua:17: attempt to call method 'map' (a nil value)
```

Is there any way to dump data inside this .lua file or just to check if stream data is the same that i expect

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest check your call to apply(). I think it should be client.query.apply(). I don't see anything obviously wrong with the udf.  client.apply() I think is for recordUDFs that operate on individual records and can change them. They don't have a map() method. For stream UDFs which is what you are writing, query.apply() would support map().

Comment: Hmm when i add client.query.apply() i got new error

'TypeError: this.isConnected is not a function in node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80'

So i assume problem is not in declaration of apply() method

Comment: var query = client.query('test', 'users', statement);  query.apply('aggregationByRegion', 'sum', function(err2, result)  {....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the [`client.apply()`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/Client.html#apply) method to apply a UDF to a single record, then you need to rewrite your `getlm` function as a [Record UDF](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/record_udf.html). (As pointed out by @pgupta.)

Example:

demo.lua:

```
function getlm(rec)
  local tuple = map()
  tuple["1"] = rec["1"]
  tuple["2"] = rec["2"]
  tuple["3"] = rec["3"]
  return tuple
end
```

apply.js:

```
const Aerospike = require('aerospike')

Aerospike
  .connect()
  .then(async client => {
    await client.udfRegister('demo.lua').then(job => job.wait())
    const key = new Aerospike.Key('test', 'test', 'test')
    await client.put(key, { '1': 'foo', '2': 'bar', '3': 'fox' })
    const udf = { module: 'demo', funcname: 'getlm'}
    const result = await client.apply(key, udf)
    console.info(result)
    client.close()
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
    if (error.client) error.client.close()
  })
```

```
$ node apply.js
{ '1': 'foo', '2': 'bar', '3': 'fox' }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JanHecking
I guess i didn't explain correctly. The thing i want to do is:
I want to get bunch of records  (stream) by some value and filter them (get only last record based on timestamp). I am using nodejs client and i am not sure how to apply my UDF on stream to return only one record (last record)